# In Express, how does router.get('/') in my routes directory handle requests other than '/'?

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

In app.js I have:

```
const routes = './routes/'
const usersRouter = require(routes +'users');

/*more code*/

app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

In users.js, I have:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

My question: How does `router.get('/')` know to get the users file? Usually I would need to pass `'/users'` to `router.get(`. But with `app.use('/users'` in app.js, all I need is `router.get('/')` in users.js. In fact if I type `router.get('/users'` in users.js the program breaks.

Learning Express, and I could use explanation of how this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have register the `usersRouter` as a middleware which will be executed when the Request URI is prefixed with `/users` an example will be `https://localhost:3000/users/` or `http://localhost:3000/users/subroute`

```
// attach `usersRouter` as middleware
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

If in your `users.js` you have define route like this

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {});
router.post('/users', (req, res) => {});
router.get('/:userId', (req, res) => {});
router.delete('/:userId', (req, res) => {}); 

module.exports = router;
```

You'll have this list of routes

1. GET => http://localhost:3000/users
2. POST => http://localhost:3000/users/users/
3. GET => http://localhost:3000/users/1
4. DELETE => http://localhost:3000/users/1

If the Request URI which you are trying to access is define in your express app, the handler will fallback to the Express buildin [Error Handler](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

So if you have define a router `router.get('/users', ...)` in the `users.js` file the application won't  break as long you are trying to reach that router with `http://...:../users/users`.

[Learn more about middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)
[Learn more about Express routing](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

That already filters to send ONLY requests that start with `/users` to the router.  It also strips off the `/users` from the start of the path so the router itself will do matching on the reduced path that has `/users` stripped from it which for `/users` will just be `/`.  For a URL like `/users/something`, the router will match against `/something`.

Thus `router.get("/", ...)` will match the original URL of `/users`, but not `/users/something`.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. I wondered why I needed '/' at all. If app.js is sending only requests beginning with '/users', why do I need even '/'?

Comment: @wesh Because you can also have routes `/users/profile` which would be installed by `router.get('/profile')`. As for why `get('/')` instead of `get('')` it's mostly a design decision of the Express developers but it also makes it more explicit what you mean and has some tradition in web development outside of Express

Answer (score 1):

The line

```js
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

will make the users router handle requests prefixed with /users. The router in the users file therefore handles not /, but /users because you told your app to use that particular router for /users/*. In reality, this is simply a shortcut of doing `router.get('/users')` instead.